# Animation not happening In React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, emotion

I am trying to achieve animation in a react app. The styles are getting imported from .js file (CSS in JS?). And those styles are getting applied except for the animation. The animation isn't working.

Styles.js containing styles is as below:

```js
import { keyframes } from '@emotion/react';

const bounceAnimation = keyframes`
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
`;
const classes = {
  loadingContainer: {
    fontSize: '84px',
    fontWeight: 800,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  loadingSpan: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    animation: `${bounceAnimation} 0.7s infinite`,
    color: 'red',
    margin: '0 -.05em',
  },
};

export default classes;
```

The React Component is as below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles';

const Loader = () => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.loadingContainer}>
      <span style={styles.loadingSpan}>loading</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use css API from '@emotion/react' like this:

```js
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css, keyframes } from '@emotion/react'

const bounce = keyframes`
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }

  70% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
`

render(
  <div
    css={css`
      animation: ${bounce} 1s ease infinite;
    `}
  >
    some bouncing text!
  </div>
)
```

UPDATE: add /** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */ is required.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: https://playcode.io/1784100

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it?